# Play multiple animations of same object at the same time

Tags: animation, three.js, timeline

I'm using a json file with one object exported from blender with 2 animations (example: walk and lift_arm). I can play animations as single and also the 2 together. That's OK, but when they play together (at the same time after doing `anim1.play()` and `anim2.play()`) it seems only half of each is played as if the time line would be run twice the speed. Why does it happen?

Comment: This question  relates also to the capability of NLA editing with json files in three.js